# parsing string to decimal doesn't return decimals JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to writing JavaScript, I'm trying to convert two values from a string to a number, however, I have tried to doing the following approaches but none seem to work.
 Example:

```
const num = parseInt('100.00') // returns 100
const num = Number('100.00') // returns 100
const num = +'100.00'; // returns 100
```

I need to return 100.00 as a number I have gone to other similar post they didn't seem to help, all knowledge is appreciated thanks!

Comment: You need to *format* that number for output in the UI? Otherwise, `100` and `100.00` are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript everything is Number, which is double-precision floating point 64 bit number (=decimal).

100.00 is equal to 100, therefore it shows you 100.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that all the approaches you have tried work.

Internally, JavaScript [stores all numbers using the floating point format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates). It uses the minimum number of decimals needed when it displays the value.

This is `0` for integer numbers as `100`. `100.00` is still `100`, adding any number of `0` after the decimal point doesn't change its value.

---

The recommended method to parse a string that looks like a number is to use [`Number.parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) or [`Number.parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat).

`parseFloat()` recognizes only numbers written in base `10` but `parseInt()` attempts to detect the base by analyzing the first characters of the input string. It automatically recognizes numbers written in bases `2`, `8`, `10` and `16` using the rules described in the [documentation page about numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Numbers). This is why it's recommended to always pass the second argument to `parseInt()` to avoid any ambiguity.

Regarding your concern, use [`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to force its representation using a certain number of decimal digits, even when the trailing digits are `0`:

```js
const num = parseInt('100.00');
console.log(num);                 // prints '100'
console.log(num.toFixed(2));      // prints '100.00'
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible, the decimal 100 is not representable as 100.00 as number, you can only represent it as a String with help of `toFixed`;

```js
var num = 100;
var strNum = num.toFixed(2); // in this case you have a string instead of a number

console.log(typeof num, num);
console.log(typeof strNum, strNum);
```